# Read and edit an .ini file with MSBuild

Tags: vb6, msbuild

I am looking for an MSBuild task/script that will allow me to control the version of an old VB6 project?

The .vbp stores the version information as .ini style, but I cannot find a simple way to read and write the three entries.

Comment: To solve my immediate problem I have used a combination of storing the version info in the msbuild script file itself and update the script file using FileUpdate.  Unfortunately I still have not got a nice way to read the current version info from the VB6 project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use the FileUpdate-task from the MSBuildCommunityTasks, found on http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

You can use regular expressions to find the pattern and then replace in the text you want.
For example: to replace the versionnumber in an assembly-info.cs:

```
<FileUpdate Files="@(VersioningAssemblyInfoFiles)"
                  Regex="AssemblyFileVersion\(&quot;.*&quot;\)\]"
                  ReplacementText="AssemblyFileVersion(&quot;$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor).$(VersionBuild).$(VersionRevision)&quot;)]" />
```

Comment: +1 For being able to write, but it doesn't help for reading the version info.

Comment: Dude, research is teh friend!  For reading from files, you can use 

      <ReadLinesFromFile File="%(SolutionToBuild.Identity)">
         <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="ItemsFromFile"/>
      </ReadLinesFromFile>

and then filter out what you need using regular expressions, or, use the freely available XmlQuery-task (from the MSBuildCommunityTasks) if your document contains xml.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that its implemented in any library

You could implement a [custom task](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx) that calls [GetPrivateProfileString](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getprivateprofilestring).

However a novel idea would be to [convert the file automatically to XML](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ini2xml.aspx) via an MSBUILD exec call and then parse that xml using the msbuild more easily.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid custom tasks as much as possible.